# Ignore citations in captions in list of figures when numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, numbering, captions, citing

When using the `\cite` command in figure captions and the `ieeetr` bibliography style, then  BibTeX numbers the citations as appearing earlier than they do in reality (i.e. the first citation in the document ends up being [42]).

Is there any way to get BibTeX to ignore the `\listoffigures` section when numbering?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the optional argument of `\caption`:

```
\caption[<Figure title>]{<Figure title> \cite{<Source>}}
```

EDIT: You'd *"still like the citation to appear in the caption in the listoffigures but just to have the number as if it were from it's position in the main body of text"*. I don't know how to do this using the `ieeetr` style, but it works out of the box using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{foo}

Some text \autocite{B02}.

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure \autocite{A01}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that but I'd still like the citation to appear in the caption in the listoffigures but just to have the number as if it were from it's position in the main body of text.  Am I asking too much?

Comment: that's done it!  I converted my document to using biblatex and it works perfectly.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 30):

This exact problem is solved by the [`notoccite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/notoccite) package written by Donald Arsenau.

I have found it throught the worth reading bibtex faq: http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf (see question 18).

Comment: `\usepackage{notoccite}` in the preamble does the magic.

Comment: If the link above is not working, the FAQ is available via CTAN at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtex