# Reference numbers out of order using BibTex

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm using `natbib`, `cleveref`, `bibtex` and `.bib` files to generate my references, using `\cite{reference}`. At first, it does it very well, but when a re-compiling is done---with the same commands---, the appearing number of the references changes, instead of having [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPntO.png), it has [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i4Kn.png). The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,hidelinks]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\mainmatter
\include{fileWithReferences}

\appendix

\backmatter

\bibliography{articles,reports,books}

\end{document}
```

Since running latex -> bibtex -> latex -> latex is time consuming at first run, how can I fix the 're-ordering'? The fileWithReferences.tex looks like:

```
\chapter{Energy}

Some text \cite{Turcotte2002}, some other text \cite{Anderson1989}. In \cref{figure:AltEn} there's a reference to a book.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.1]{Alternative_Energies.jpg}
    \caption{Alternative energies \cite{Anderson1989}}
    \label{figure:AltEn}
\end{figure}

Here another reference \cite{Turcotte2002}.
```

And the books.bib file looks like:

```
@book{Turcotte2002,
author = {D.L. Turcotte and G. Schubert},
title = {Geodynamics},
year = {2002},
OPTedition = {2nd.},
}

@book{Anderson1989,
author = {Don. L. Anderson},
title = {Theory of the Earth},
year = {1989},
}
```

Output (first run):

[image: Output (first run)]

Output (second run):

[image: Output (second run)]

Comment: You can't be using `biblatex` and `natbib` at the same time and in fact the example file you include does not employ the `biblatex` package (i.e., there's no `\usepackage{biblatex}`).  In addition, in order for others to examine the problem you describe, you must include at least one or two `\cite`s.  The line `\include{fileWithReferences}` is not something any one can test.

Comment: Without information about the relevant contents of `filewithreferences.tex`, it's not possible to say for sure what's going on. It could be something as simple as an extra `\cite` command that has slipped in somewhere in the file.

Comment: Thanks for editing your posting to provide information about `fileswithreferences.tex` and `books.bib`. I must confess it's now unclear to me what your question or concern is. Please elaborate. Incidentally, while it may be helpful (or even important) to a citation call-out in the caption of a `figure` while you're looking at the figure, it's probably less useful (and possibly quite confusing) to have the numeric citation number show up in the List of Figures. You may thus want to write the caption command as `\caption[Alternative energies]{Alternative energies \cite{Anderson1989}}`.

Comment: As you can see by the output images, reference numbers order change when a re-compiling is done. it doesn't happen if I don't put references in a figure caption. 
In my batch file I have to include delete commands for any output file generated by latex and bibtex, but this is time-consuming. I want to know why the order change and how I can fix it (just re-compiling).

Comment: @Mico -- That might actually be the solution: I think the use of `unsrtnat` is (eventually) causing `[2]` to become `[1]` *because* it is appearing earlier in the document as part of the LoF.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/ignore-citations-in-captions-in-list-of-figures-when-numbering As an alternative to the suggestion of using the optional argument for the caption, you could try loading the `notoccite` package.

Comment: Thanks! Although I'll do a lot of editing, it won't happen again.

Comment: Works flawlessly with the notoccite package. Thaks again.