# Bibliography referencing backwards, help

Tags: bibliographies, compiling

I am finishing my first latex setup for my thesis and I decided to test out the figures and tables and how to control them together with the referencing and bibliography. Everything was going fine; the first time I cited references and corss-referenced material the bibliography compiled in the order in which citations appear in the text (desired result), then I played around with the figures and suddenly my bibliography is compiling from the bottom up (figures/tables first).

I must be making a rookie mistake, but I reproduced the same effect in an MWE of my stripped down thesis setup below.

Please could someone explain why it is doing this all of a sudden? I am currently using `sharelatex.com` as my editor. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % list subsubsections

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}

\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}

\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}

\minitoc

\section{Summary of Achievements}
Text goes here

\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text

\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out \cite{Guittonneau201071}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{This is an example table \cite{Li2012}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
This & is & an & example.\\\hline
This & is & an & example.
\end{tabular}
\label{example.table}
\end{table}

So this continues with the Table~\ref{example.table}

\begin{figure}
\setcapindent{1em}
\fbox{\parbox{.95\linewidth}{\centering{\KOMAScript}}}
\caption{Example \cite{Fu2009789} with slightly indented caption
starting at the second line}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

The bib references I used are the following:

```
@article{Song20084290
,   author  = {M.S. Song and B. Huang and M.X. Zhang and J.G. Li}
,   title   = {Formation and growth mechanism of ZrC hexagonal platelets synthesized by self-propagating reaction}
,   journal = {Journal of Crystal Growth}
,   year    = {2008}
,   volume  = {310}
,   number  = {18}
,   pages   = {4290 - 4294}
,   issn    = {0022-0248}
,   doi = {10.1016/j.jcrysgro.2008.07.016}
,   url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022024808005678}
,   keywords    = {B1. Zirconium carbide}
}

@article{Guittonneau201071
,   author  = {Fabrice Guittonneau and Abdesselam Abdelouas and Bernd Grambow}
,   title   = {HTR Fuel Waste Management: TRISO separation and acid-graphite intercalation compounds preparation}
,   journal = {Journal of Nuclear Materials}
,   year    = {2010}
,   volume  = {407}
,   number  = {2}
,   pages   = {71 - 77}
,   issn    = {0022-3115}
,   doi = {DOI: 10.1016/j.jnucmat.2010.09.026}
,   url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022311510005027}
}

@article{Fu2009789
,   author  = {Hongzhi Fu and Weimin Peng and Tao Gao}
,   title   = {Structural and elastic properties of ZrC under high pressure}
,   journal = {Materials Chemistry and Physics}
,   year    = {2009}
,   volume  = {115}
,   number  = {2–3}
,   pages   = {789 - 794}
,   issn    = {0254-0584}
,   doi = {10.1016/j.matchemphys.2009.02.031}
,   url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0254058409001163}
,   keywords    = {<span style='font-style: italic'>Ab initio</span> calculations}
}

@article{Li2012
,   author  = {Qinggang Li and Haijun Zhou and Shaoming Dong and Zhen Wang and Ping He and Jinshan Yang and Bin Wu and Jianbao Hu}
,   title   = {Fabrication of a ZrC–SiC matrix for ceramic matrix composites and its properties}
,   journal = {Ceramics International}
,   year    = {2012}
,   number  = {0}
,   pages   = { - }
,   issn    = {0272-8842}
,   doi = {10.1016/j.ceramint.2012.01.023}
,   url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272884212000260}
,   keywords    = {ZrC precursor}
}
```

Comment: It's because you've added list of figures/tables, which are printed before the text. Use the `notoccite` package, or the optional argument for the caption, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/ignore-citations-in-captions-in-list-of-figures-when-numbering/84333#84333

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Thank you for the suggestion, I didn't know of that package so all the better, I have implemented yours as I have the below answer and everything works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

instead of

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

and make sure you delete most of the other output files like .aux .bbl before you rerun latex. I just leave tex and bib files. I would recommend to use [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) instead of bibtex because it has more control. Here is the output in order. [image: In order]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it didn't occur to me to delete the files until you mentioned it, but given that I have been playing around on the online editor `sharelatex.com` for which there is no way to access and delete those files.

Comment: @Aung `ieeetr` is not the official bibliography style for `IEEE`, it's `IEEEtran`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Given answer didn't work for me. Use following

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

instead of

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate on what this does for other people's sake?