# Stop Classicthesis starting its reference count from figure captions

Tags: bibliographies, captions

I'm currently using the classicthesis style and I noticed that it places a list of figure captions as part of the preamble. Now I have references in my figure captions so the result is the reference order starts counting from these references. So when the text actually starts, the "first" reference is something like [15] instead. Is there anyway to start counting from after the preambles but retain my references in the list of figure captions?

Comment: (1) Welcome! (2) Don't use classicthesis. (3) Do post a small, complete document which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce your problem. (A Minimum Working Example or MWE.)

Comment: From the description, it seems you are interested in the `notoccite` package. See [Ignore citations in captions in list of figures when numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/)

Comment: Thanks for the link egreg. Using biblatex to compile my bibliography seems to have solved that issue. The [biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots) link also helped.