# Bibliography exasperation: References in numerical order, as they appear in document

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, cross-referencing, citing

I have been searching around online trying to figure out why my references appear to be numbered in a seemingly random order. I have read probably 20 different webpages in total, including many questions on this site and I cannot fix the problem.

However so far I have learned that `biblatex` and `bibtex` are not the same thing? My guess is there are loads of different "bibliography executables/programs/compilers" (?) [I have no idea what you actually call something like biblatex] and I think this has been one source of confusion.

The most simple thing to do is give you my main tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\myname}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=-,range-units=single}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}


\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{mymacros}

\extrafloats{100}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

    \input{title.tex}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter{Chapter 1...}
    \input{chapters/chapter1.tex}

    \input{chapters/theory.tex}

    \clearpage
    \section{Conclusion}

    \chapter{Appendix}
    \input{chapters/appendix.tex}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I compile this with texstudio, and the first reference number is `[8]`. The next is `[12]`. I want the order to be `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

I can provide the references.bib file, but essentially it looks like this (here are a few examples)

```
% normal/inverted heirachy image
@article{Artusa:2014wnl,
    author         = "Artusa, D. R. and others",
    title          = "{Exploring the Neutrinoless Double Beta Decay in the
    Inverted Neutrino Hierarchy with Bolometric Detectors}",
    collaboration  = "CUORE",
    journal        = "Eur. Phys. J.",
    volume         = "C74",
    year           = "2014",
    pages          = "3096",
    doi            = "10.1140/epjc/s10052-014-3096-8",
    eprint         = "1404.4469",
    archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
    primaryClass   = "nucl-ex",
    SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1404.4469;%%"
}

% KATRIN paper
@article{1703.05272,
    Author = {J. Behrens and P. C. -O. Ranitzsch and M. Beck and A. Beglarian and M. Erhard and S. Groh and V. Hannen and M. Kraus and H. -W. Ortjohann and O. Rest and K. Schlösser and T. Thümmler and K. Valerius and K. Wierman and J. F. Wilkerson and D. Winzen and M. Zacher and C. Weinheimer},
    Title = {A pulsed, mono-energetic and angular-selective UV photo-electron source for the commissioning of the KATRIN experiment},
    Year = {2017},
    Eprint = {1703.05272},
    Eprinttype = {arXiv},
    Doi = {10.1140/epjc/s10052-017-4972-9},
}
```

I can't think of anything else which would be useful. I hope it is a simple mistake that I have made because this has been confusing me all morning and I have not been able to resolve the issue.

Here is a screenshot to demonstrate the issue...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Add `sorting=none` to the options for `biblatex`

Comment: You have not posted much to help test but are you sure that is the first reference? In particular do you have `\cite` in captions that appear earlier in a list of figures?

Comment: See also [Biblatex citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That screenshot is the first page with actual content contained. The first chapter is currently blank. There is a `\listoffigures` command and some of those figures do have citations in them. Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: @egreg I have added that and the results are the same

Comment: After you added `sorting=none` you should delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and recompile.

Comment: [Ignore citations in captions in list of figures when numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36304/35864) shows that a list of figures should not be a problem for the citation order in `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe Ah, that seems to have done the trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: I actually discovered a fix while working through the linked question above - I stripped all non ascii characters from my reference.bib file, renaming it as a new file and that seems to have also solved the problem. Taking into account what you said about deleting the output files, my guess would be changing the input file to biblatex forced this to happen?

Comment: This is actually quite strange because I did try deleting the .aux etc files earlier and that didn't help. Could it be that non-ascii characters cause problems too?

Comment: It could be that renaming the file has similar results to deleting temporary files. Non-ASCII chars should not be a problem at all, especially when you use Biber, expect if you use them in the entrykeys. But the symptoms should be different in that case.

Comment: What do get if you add "ß" in your main document?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just saw you use BibTeX. That could be a problem if you were to sort by names, but since you sort by occurrence theoretically that should be no problem. But note that BibTeX does not support unicode so you can't expect it to work properly anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I add that character, nothing appears in the output.

Comment: Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and try again.