# Why does in-text citation counter reset when bibliography fills its first page?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

When I tried to cite reference number 10 in the text, the counter reset back to 1. [image: see the attached image] [image]

When I got back to References page at the end of report, it appeared that the first page of bibliography filled up to number 9, and LaTeX is kind of doesn't know what to do to move to next page of bibliography, so it restarted counting from 1! Am I write? I don't know If how to deal with it.

These are the problem-related segments in my main code, do you think something is missing?

```
\documentclass[English,MSC,Times,NoIndent,IEEE]{mfthesis}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

Power steering was first introduced on passenger vehicles as HPAS system 
\cite{lamm1999}. In HPAS, assist torque is driven by a hydraulic system 
composed mainly of engine-driven pump, fluid reservoir, control valve and 
hydraulic cylinder \cite{watson2006}\cite{erjavec2009}. On the other hand, 
electric power assisted steering EPAS (Figure 1.1) is an electromechanical 
subsystem which provides the driver with the required amount of torque, using 
a controllable electric motor \cite{eletimes2019}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibdata}

\end{document}
```

.bib file is as following:

```
@book{harrer2017steering,
    title={Steering handbook},
    author={Harrer, Manfred and Pfeffer, Peter},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Springer}
}

@inproceedings{chatterjee2013mathematical,
    title={Mathematical modelling of automotive electric power assist-steering system},
    author={Chatterjee, Mayurika and Rajguru, Chaitanya and Wadkar, Aditya},
    booktitle={2013 International Conference on Advances in Computing, Communications and Informatics (ICACCI)},
    pages={1389--1396},
    year={2013},
    organization={IEEE}
}

@book{newcomb1989technical,
    title={A technical history of the motor car},
    author={Newcomb, Thomas Peter and Spurr, Robert Thomas},
    year={1989},
    publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{schultz1985, 
author = {M. Schultz},
    title = {Steering: A Century of Progress},
    journal = {Popular Mechanics},
    issue_date = {May 1985},
    volume = {162},
    number = {5},
    month = may,
    year = {1985},
    issn = {0032-4558},
    pages = {52--60},
    numpages = {9},
    publisher = {The Hearst Magazines},
    address = {Eighth Avenue, NY, USA},
}

@article{howe1956,
    author = {H. E. Howe},
    title = {Mr. Power Steering's Ship Comes In},
    journal = {Popular Science},
    issue_date = {Feb 1956},
    volume = {168},
    number = {2},
    month = February,
    year = {1956},
    issn = {0161-7370},
    pages = {161--164},
    numpages = {4},
    publisher = {Popular Science Publishing Co.,Inc.},
    address = {Fourth Avenue, New York 10, NY, USA},
}

@article{lamm1999,
    author = {M. Lamm},
    title = {75 years of Chryslers},
    journal = {Popular Mechanics},
    issue_date = {Mar 1999},
    volume = {176},
    number = {3},
    month = March,
    year = {1999},
    issn = {0032-4558},
    numpages = {3},
    publisher = {The Hearst Corporation},
    address = {Eighth Avenue, NY, USA},
}

@article{watson2006,
    author = {B. Watson},
    title = {History of Power Steering},
    journal = {Imperial Automobile Club Archives},
    issue_date = {Mar 2006},
}

@book{erjavec2009,
    title={Automotive Technology: A Systems Approach},
    author={Erjavec, Jack},
    year={2009},
    publisher={Cengage Learning}
} 

@online{eletimes2019,
    title={Chipset Solution for Electric Power Steering Systems}, 
    author={G. Keser and C. Unterreiner},
    url={https://www.eletimes.com/chipset-solution-for-electric-power steering-systems},
    note={January 2019},
}
```

Any help Please?

**Note: I am using BibTeX to format my bibliography.**

Comment: Where did you get `mfthesis.cls` form? It is not a standard documentclass.

Comment: It's given to me from my supervisor as a folder built by him. Anyway, when I compile it using TeXstudio, it worked very well. I am a quite beginner in LaTeX, sorry for this primitive discussion.

Comment: From a quick test I did with the `article` document class, the behaviour you describe is very likely related to this documentclass as I could not reproduce it with `article`. Could you please also try with `article` and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I have done that. It was working well with correct number sequence, until I reached reference number 10, it reset citing counter to 1. I will add the bib file at the moment.

Comment: @leandriis you mean change the document class to `article` and change everything accordingly? its not easy for me to make all these changes.

Comment: Make a cop of your problematic document. In this copy remove everything between `\begni{document}` and `\end{document}`. Add 10 citations. Compile. Does this still reproduce the issue? If so, replace the documentclass to `article`, recompile and see if the problem persists. If not, the issue is related to the documentclass. If the issue is also there with the `article` documentclass, the issue is unrelated to your documentclass.

Comment: note `author={G. Keser, C. Unterreiner},` should be `author={G. Keser and C. Unterreiner},` author names are always separated by `and` in bibtex, commas are just used to separate first and last names of the same author, as in `Carlisle, David`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I really apologize for that, I thought that will be easier and give a clear idea. Now the actual bib file is inserted in the question, and the citations A,B,C and D are replaced with the actual citations in bib file as well. When LaTeX reaches number 9, it resets automatically to 1, and put the latest reference as the first in references list!

Comment: @AliM.EidBashabsheh: The bib file you show only contains a total of 9 different references. Why would you expect 10 different references in your bibliography then?

Comment: I didn't tell my problem well. Let me explain clearly: I have a total of 9 references, not 10. When I reached reference no. 8 (its key is erjavec2009 in bib file) everything was OK. Then when I added reference no. 9 (its key is eletimes2019 in bib file), in-text citation reset to 1 and References list showed this last reference as the first one instead of being in its order (must be no.9). I hope I make it clear, it needs some focus.

Comment: also if possible use article class or another standard class

Comment: Just a wild guess: do you cite the problematic reference in a caption or a section/chapter title?

Comment: @leandriis that would be my guess. as I said above [1] almost certainly does appear first in the file.

Comment: @leandriis Yes exactly I did cite it in a caption in a chapter of my thesis.

Comment: And you also have a list of figure or list of tables in the beginning of your document, right? The easiest fix for that would be not showing the reference in the list of figures/tables. If you're OK with that, you can use \caption[without reference] {with reference}. The text in [] will be used in the list of... while the text in {} will be used with the figure/table.

Comment: See also : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36304/134144

Comment: I am confused about that. I tried to understand but its too weird to me. How the list of figures has things to do with reference numbering?!!

Comment: I got the idea now, I'm trying to fix everything, it seems its gonna work, Thank you very much guys, you saved my day.