# Referencing error in thesis

Tags: natbib

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{Thesis}

  \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{bm}
      \usepackage{afterpage}
       \usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}
        \usepackage{pifont}
         \usepackage{pdfpages}
          \usepackage{mciteplus}
           \usepackage{fancyhdr}
            \usepackage{cleveref}
             \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
              \usepackage{algpseudocode}
               \usepackage{algorithm}
                \usepackage{tabularx}
             \usepackage{multirow}
             \usepackage{booktabs}
           \usepackage{siunitx}
            \usepackage{setspace}
             \usepackage{subcaption}
              \usepackage{setspace}
               \usepackage{tikz}
                \usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
                 \pdfminorversion=7
                   \hypersetup{pdfauthor={Name}}
                    \let\Algorithm\algorithm
                   \renewcommand\algorithm[1][]{\Algorithm[#1]\setstretch{0.7}}
                 \makeatletter
      \DeclareMathOperator*{\Motimes}{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\bigotimes$}}}}
         \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure}
       \newcommand{\xmark}{\text{\ding{55}}}
        \makeatother
         \usepackage[square, sort&compress, numbers]{natbib}
         \DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
          \graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
          \hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true}
         \title{\ttitle}

        \begin{document}

      \makeatletter
       \renewcommand*{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
       \makeatother
      \frontmatter
        \setstretch{1.6}
       \fancyhead{}
        %\rhead{\thepage}
         %\cfoot{\thepage} gives page number at bottom
           %\lhead{}
           %\pagestyle{fancy}

          \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
            \hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
            \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
              \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
                 \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}

                \include{Others/Titlepage1}
               \clearpage
               %\include{Others/Titlepage2}
                     \include{Others/Declaration}
                    \clearpage
                \include{Others/Abstract}
               \clearpage
         \include{Others/Publications}
        \clearpage
        \include{Others/Acknowledge}
       \clearpage
      \include{Others/Dedication}
      \pagestyle{plain}

      \tableofcontents
      \listoffigures
      \listoftables
      \clearpage

        \mainmatter
         \pagestyle{fancy}
          \fancyfoot{}
          \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\thepage}
           \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}

         \include{Chapters/Chapter1/Chapter1}
           \include{Chapters/Chapter3/Chapter3}
             \include{Chapters/Chapter2/Chapter2}
              \include{Chapters/Chapter4/Chapter4}
         \include{Chapters/Chapter5/Chapter5}



        \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}
        \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}
          \backmatter

           \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
           \bibliography{Bibliography}

              \end{document}
```

I have all the references in the .bib file (Bibliography).

The issue I have is that when i compile till the 4th chapter, i.e.,

```
                  \include{Chapters/Chapter1/Chapter1}
                      \include{Chapters/Chapter3/Chapter3}
                       \include{Chapters/Chapter2/Chapter2}
                           \include{Chapters/Chapter4/Chapter4}
```

All the references are okay, but as soon as I compile including the fifth chapter, i.e.,

```
                               \include{Chapters/Chapter1/Chapter1}
                      \include{Chapters/Chapter3/Chapter3}
                       \include{Chapters/Chapter2/Chapter2}
                           \include{Chapters/Chapter4/Chapter4}
                             \include{Chapters/Chapter5/Chapter5}
```

There is an issue. The main problem here is that it is neither shown as a warning nor as an error by latex. The problem is that there is a reference that is cited in Chapter 1, which should have a reference number around 80, but when i include the 5th chapter this reference is coming as the First reference of the thesis. I did all kinds of permutations by running the bibliography, the compiling, then running, but to no avail. It is really very frustrating, can somebody help?

Comment: Note that you are better of making this into a single self contained example such that others can copy it and test. We don't have your chapters so we cannot help with what you have given.

Comment: Are there maybe entries in the bib file that have the same `key`?

Comment: No there is no duplicate keys, i have searched the .bib file for the same key

Comment: If the problem is indeed caused by citations in captions, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36304/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61869/35864.

Comment: Yes it was due to citations in caption. I corrected it out using ``\makeatletter
\let\oldcite\cite
\pretocmd{\listoffigures}{\def\cite{\ignorespaces\@gobble}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\listoffigures}{\let\cite\oldcite}{}{}
\makeatother``