# Latex ignoring cross-references in list of figures and tables

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, captions

My question is somewhat opposite to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/ignore-citations-in-captions-in-list-of-figures-when-numbering) question.

In my document, latex (pdflatex) is correctly cross-referring to other sections, figures, or tables in captions of figures and tables.
However,in the list of figures and list of tables for the same cross-references I see "??".

Any insights on what could be the reasons? Please feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: either you have not run latex enough times to resolve the cross references, or there is an error in your `\ref` or `\label`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think there is an error in my ref and label. As I mentioned in the question, the same cross-reference is showing correctly in the text. But is not appearing in the list of tables or figures.

I do not understand what do you mean by running enough times?

Comment: Unless you show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to get fixed, the odds aren't good that anyone will be able to come up with a diagnosis of the situation, let alone suggest a cure. You may also want to clarify that the "it" in "it shows ?? in the list of figures and list of tables" refers to.

Comment: What kinds of cross-referencing instructions do you place in the captions of figures and tables? Please advise.

Comment: @PHcoDer the first time you run latex after adding a `\label` or `\cite` you _always_ get `??` for the `\ref` or `\cite` and a warning telling you to re-run latex, it can take two or three runs for all cross references to resolve. So it may be you simply need to run latex again, or you have an error in your document but in the latter case you will need to show the code if you want someone to debug it.

Comment: @Mico and @ David Carlisle, Thanks for the response. I am using \label and \ref combination for intra-document cross referencing. And \cite for bib. The issue was with label and ref combo. It got resolved when I ran latex 4 times. Thanks.