# Citation becomes disordered after using command "\listoffigures"

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing my thesis in Overleaf. and I'm now trying to generate a content of figures using the command "\listoffigures", and now the content of figures is generated, but all citations become dosordered. :(

```
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\clearpage
```

And when I delete the command "\listoffigures", they become again in the correct order (start from [1],[2],[3],[4]...).

I also tried the command "\bibliographystyle{unsrt}" but it's not helping.

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\renewcommand\bibname{Reference}
\bibliography{Reference}
```

The citations in the doc "Reference.bib" are generated by citaiv and copied to Overleaf. They are not in the order how I cited them, but I think it shouldn't be a problem.
Doest anybody know why???

Comment: It's probably the issue discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36304/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61869/35864. (That is to say, you probably cited in the caption and if the `\listoffigures` is printed then those entries are cited "too early" in the document.)

Comment: OMG that's the problem! Now I see it! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. Just need to add a package `\usepackage{notoccite}` and now everything works:)

Comment: The `notoccite` manual says "that it may well fail when used with various packages for citations or cross refernces." Much safer to do the recommended thing of using the optional `\caption` argument omitting the citation. as per the `nottoccite` manual and the SE references by @moewe.