# How to stop unsrt from counting figure list as first citation appearance?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using unsrt style but the reference list is showing a very weird order

[image]

And the first citation I have used in text is showing as number [10], apparently, it sorted my references as my figures list appearance:

[image]\

How do i stop it from counting in the figure list as first appearance and start from the text?

Comment: the usual way is `\caption[caption with no cite]{long caption with cite}`

Comment: @modnar the order of entries in the bib file has no effect.

Comment: @mushter, I guess it's because the `\listoffigures` command precedes your main text?

Comment: @modnar probably, which is why i want to give it some sort of way to tell it not to count it in

Comment: @DavidCarlisle works great, thank you!

Comment: @mushter In addition to David's solution, there are other related information at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/ignore-citations-in-captions-in-list-of-figures-when-numbering