# Using Bibtex IEEEtran and sorting by citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing, ieeetran, sorting

I'm currently writing my thesis, and I've got feedback about my bibliography not beeing numbered by order of citation.
We have been provided a template to use, but it isn't 100% functional, because I've already changed a few things so it doesn't throw any errors.

The compiler is LuaLaTex.
I'm using Mendeley to create the bibliography and importing it automatically to Overleaf using the paid feature.

The template for the bibliography:

```
\thispagestyle{bibpagestyle} % defined in configDocument.tex

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\vspace*{48pt}
\section*{\fontsize{16}{12} \textbf{\headReferences}}
\label{sec:References}
\markboth{{\headReferences}}{{\headReferences}}

\renewcommand\bibname{}
\vspace*{-48pt}
\def\thispagestyle#1{} 
\thispagestyle{bib}
\justify
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bib/references} % filename .bib with the bibliography
\endgroup
```

I'm expecting to have an output as:

```
The first citation [1], then later comes the second [2] and so on [3]...

[1] First citation
[2] Second citation
[3] Third citation
```

I've already been looking for older posts adressing this issue, but doesn't seem to be anything to help.
Some say to use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`, but this changes the style demanded by the organization, wich is no solution.

Also, writing the full .bib by hand is no solution as well, because of the extensive bibliography I currently have...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! If possible, could you please extend your code into an example that compile please, starting with your `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It means we do not have to build your code (that we may get wrong) and can answer quicker, thanks

Comment: Please can you give a full example, using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` in a basic document I get citations ordered by appearance (note a citation may appear out of place if it is cited in something like `\caption` or `\section` and then appears in a  list of figures or table of contents) .

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll try to compile everything into a working code. The current template is dividid in groups and this group is called into the main text file. It may take me some time, but no later than tomorrow.

Comment: @DaiBowen, you are onto something there! I checked the list of figures and there they are in order. Is there a way to change that, so the main text is the one defining de order for the citations?

Comment: Try answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36304/106162).

Comment: Thank you @DaiBowen, using the option ```\caption``` argument worked!
```\caption[<Figure title>]{<Figure title> \cite{<Source>}}```

Comment: Great, glad it's resolved